# keeping a detached ssh process running *after closing the ssh client*

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, background-process, tmux

I ssh in to my ubuntu machine usimg mobaxterm.

This works very well.

Sometimes I want to keep a process running but exit my ssh session (and exit mobaxterm). I have tried the following but regardless as soon as I close mobaxterm my process on the target machine dies, using firefox as an example:

```
ssh => 
tmux;
firefox & disown;
tmux detach;
exit;

ssh => 
screen firefox & disown;
exit;
```

I'm sure I've made a really stupid mistake but looking around other posts on this topic I thought I had followed their recomendations but to no evail.

thanks in advance.

Clarification:
**I can detach my process succesfully using screen or nohup, but is it possible to shut the ssh client and keep the detached process running?**

Comment: also have a look at disown http://serverfault.com/questions/34750/is-it-possible-to-detach-a-process-from-its-terminal-or-i-should-have-used-s?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I nohup/screen an already-started process?](http://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process)

Comment: Do I read that right, that you start firefox with X11 forwarding and when you close the connection, you are surprised, that the firefox does not continue to run in your session?

Answer (score 1):

Two options to avoid automatic killing a detached process:

1. Using screen: screen is an Unix utility which allows you to keep a live session, after your logged-out.

   - To start screen, enter the following command:

   screen

   - Detach but keep shell window open

   > press Ctrl a d

   - Resume your screen session:

   screen -r

You should use screen in the following way:

1. ssh into the server
2. start screen
3. execute the commands you want to run
4. detach screen (ctrl-a-d)
5. exit the server andclose ssh connection

The processes should keep running in the server

You'll be able to see it, when you'll:

6. ssh into the server
7. resume screen `screen -r`
8. check relevant logs,  `ps -ef` , etc

More info:

- [screen gnu page](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)
- [basic screen commands](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acuy)

  2. Using `nohup` - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

  nohup unix_command &

More info:
- [man nohup](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)

Comment: As per my op, I've tried screen, I've also tried nohup, but when I exit my ssh client (mobaxterm) the process I started is killed. So I suppose what I am asking is, is it possible to shut the ssh client and keep the detached process running?

Comment: @danm - screen should work, I've updated my answer with step-by-step instructions how to use screen

Answer (score 0):

> Clarification: I can detach my process succesfully using screen or nohup, but is it possible to shut the ssh client and keep the detached process running?

Yes.

This is remarkably easy to test for yourself too.

Comment: ok, well thats not my experience, so something else must be going on

Comment: I use ssh + screen all the time. It just works.

Comment: what ssh client do you use?

Comment: putty/kitty and openssh.

Comment: I have just tried putty, I can detach the process fine (as with mobaxterm) but if I shut the actual putty app my detached process is also killed.

Comment: They you are doing something wrong.

Comment: brilliant insight.