# Can you screen a running programme?

Tags: linux, bash, process, gnu-screen, job-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I nohup/screen an already-started process?](https://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process)

GNU screen is great for long running programmes. You can start your programme in it and disconnect and bring your laptop home.

However sometimes I start a programme outside screen and it takes longer than I want. I have no problem with pausing the programme using <kbd>Control</kbd> - <kbd>Z</kbd> etc., however I don't want to restart it cause then it'll take ages to run again. Is there some way I can move an existing running process into a screen session?

Comment: Dupe: http://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process

Comment: Yes you can. Reptyr was made just for that purpose: http://serverfault.com/a/284795/235596

Comment: Not dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process , but is dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/55880/moving-an-already-running-process-to-screen/284795
As @newUserNameHere mentioned, reptyr is a good solution which is a possible solution to both problems, but still different kind of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry, you can't.

Furthermore I do the same as David Mackintosh. Where ever I am, I start my screen (although I use screen -x). Almost everything I do on my server is running inside my screen, with about 20 screen windows open.

In that case, it will not mind if something is taking a bit longer.

Comment: yes you can do it, use `reptyr`, see:  http://serverfault.com/a/284795

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is "no".

After having some horrible experiences with poor wireless connectivity and long-running processes, I reflexively run EVERYTHING in screen sessions now.  My first command on connecting to a system is nearly always

```
$ screen -ADR
```

...and I go from there.

Comment: mosh is a nice alternative also