# Moving an already-running process to Screen

Tags: linux, vnc, gnu-screen

My office job routinely sees me connected to a Linux box via VNC.

Sometimes I start a remote job on the console, and realize later that it runs much longer than expected. (Should have started that one under Screen in the first place...)

I don't want to keep my workstation running overnight just to keep the VNC session open; I would like  to move that already-running remote job into a Screen session (on the remote box), so I can power down the workstation (and reconnect next morning).

How can this be done, if at all?

Comment: and it's a dupe, http://serverfault.com/questions/49877/can-you-screen-and-running-programme - seems it can't be done.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/28568/screen-a-running-process

Comment: Also see [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I nohup/screen an already-started process?](http://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process)

Comment: Search for screenify script.

Comment: Is there a macOS version for this?

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Have a look at [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr), which does exactly that.  The github page has all the information.

> ### reptyr - A tool for "re-ptying" programs.
>
> reptyr is a utility for taking an
>   existing running program and attaching
>   it to a new terminal. Started a
>   long-running process over ssh, but
>   have to leave and don't want to
>   interrupt it? Just start a screen, use
>   reptyr to grab it, and then kill the
>   ssh session and head on home.
>
> ### USAGE
>
> reptyr PID
>
> "reptyr PID" will grab the process
>   with id PID and attach it to your
>   current terminal.
>
> After attaching, the process will take
>   input from and write output to the new
>   terminal, including ^C and ^Z.
>   (Unfortunately, if you background it,
>   you will still have to run "bg" or
>   "fg" in the old terminal. This is
>   likely impossible to fix in a
>   reasonable way without patching your
>   shell.)

Comment: If, like me, you looked at the link above and briefly considered installing the program from source, take heart: it's just an `apt-get` away on Debian systems.

Comment: This is awesome!  I'd upvote it 10 times if I could!  Also, reptyr is available in RedHat repos as well.  Just 'yum install' to get it.

Comment: Doesn't work except in the most trivial cases: `Unable to attach. (This most commonly means that 11690 has a suprocesses)`

Comment: At least as root, you can use `reptyr -T PID`

Comment: Note to Ubuntu users:  reptyr depends on the ptrace(2) system call to attach to the  remote  program.  On  Ubuntu Maverick and  higher,  this ability is disabled by default for security reasons. You can enable it temporarily by doing `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` as root, or permanently by  editing  the  file  `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf`,  which  also contains more information about this setting. Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/reptyr.1.html

Comment: Is there a way to do this with commands running in a pipe?

Comment: That's such a nice tool, worked flawless for a php console process.
Thanks for saving me hours of work :)

Comment: How to use this wonderful utility on Raspberry Pi 4 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? I don't see it via apt-get.

Comment: Is there a macOS version for this?

Comment: Hah, the process that I want to attach to is yum, which blocks me from installing reptyr until it has finished :) Oh, well I'll now I know, and can have it installed for the next time.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work for `psql`: `[-] Process 1211525 (sudo) shares 1211526's process group. Unable to attach.
(This most commonly means that 1211526 has suprocesses).
Unable to attach to pid 1211526: Invalid argument`
Attaching to both processes fails.

Answer (score 58):

You cannot do this, easily. I'd suggest making it a habit to start screen as the first thing you do after opening a console.

However, for your actual problem, there's another thing you could try: after having launched your job from the terminal, background it by typing ctrl-z and then `bg`. After that, detach the job from it's parent shell; in bash you'd do `disown -h %<jobid>`. After that, you can safely close the terminal and the job will continue running.

Comment: This worked very well for my case.  reptyr and retty both failed to grab the process, but all I needed was to be able to close a terminal and leave the process to run.

Comment: FYI: after _disown_-ing the process it can be _reptyr_-ed inside _screen_.

Comment: This killed my running program :(

Comment: Improving [the comment by](https://serverfault.com/questions/55880/moving-an-already-running-process-to-screen/55882#comment715009_55881) @Adam ([Adam](https://serverfault.com/users/219726/adam)): FYI: after `disown`-ing the process it can be `reptyr`-ed (as described in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/284795/515968)) inside `screen`.

Comment: Works fine. To test it I did:  `mkdir /tmp/fifo1`. Then used `cat /tmp/fifo1` as the command to be detach from `tty`.

Answer (score 41):

As you're using Linux, what about using [retty](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/retty.1.html) inside the newly launched screen process?

```
$ screen -S my_process
$ retty $(pgrep my_process)
/redraw
```

Comment: Didn't know of retty, thanks. However, for the kind of long-running jobs I have in mind, I'm a bit reluctant to use a tool that refers to itself as "very lightly tested". I go with earl's solution.

Comment: see no retty in Gentoo

Comment: cannot attach to 4858

Comment: no retty in debian11

Comment: @piotao [`reptyr` is `apt-get`able for debian](https://serverfault.com/a/284795/515968) and [`yum install`able on RedHat Repos (CentOS,...)](https://serverfault.com/questions/55880/moving-an-already-running-process-to-screen/55882#comment1019204_284795)

Comment: @arnold Maybe [similar to this](https://serverfault.com/questions/55880/moving-an-already-running-process-to-screen/55882#comment1116643_284795)?