# Opening an existing process

Tags: linux, unix, remote-desktop, process, top

I am using Eclipse in Linux through a remote connection (xrdp).  My internet got disconnected, so I got disconnected from the server while eclipse was running.

Now I logged in again, and I do the "top" command I can see that eclipse is running and still under my user name.

Is there some way I can bring that process back into my view (I do not want to kill it because I am in the middle of checking in a large swath of code)?  It doesnt show up on the bottom panel after I logged in again.

Here is the "top" output:

```
/home/mclouti% top
top - 08:32:31 up 43 days, 13:06, 29 users,  load average: 0.56, 0.79, 0.82
Tasks: 447 total,   1 running, 446 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  6.0%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 92.1%id,  1.1%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3107364k total,  2975852k used,   131512k free,    35756k buffers
Swap:  2031608k total,    59860k used,  1971748k free,   817816k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
13415 mclouti   15   0  964m 333m  31m S 21.2 11.0  83:12.96 eclipse
16040 mclouti   15   0  2608 1348  888 R  0.7  0.0   0:00.12 top
31395 mclouti   15   0 29072  20m 8524 S  0.7  0.7 611:08.08 Xvnc
 2583 root      20   0  898m 2652 1056 S  0.3  0.1 139:26.82 automount
28990 postgres  15   0 13564  868  304 S  0.3  0.0  26:33.36 postgres
28995 postgres  16   0 13808 1248  300 S  0.3  0.0   6:54.95 postgres
31440 mclouti   15   0  3072 1592 1036 S  0.3  0.1   6:01.54 gam_server
    1 root      15   0  2072  524  496 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.00 init
    2 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:04.53 migration/0
    3 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.04 ksoftirqd/0
    4 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0
    5 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.72 migration/1
    6 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.07 ksoftirqd/1
    7 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1
    8 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:04.33 migration/2
    9 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.05 ksoftirqd/2
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running the X session on Xvnc. If that's correct you just need to connect again to the vnc service has you were doing before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use xrdp, but Eclypse was probably left running on a different X display. If your client doesn't allow you to reattach to an existing display instead of creating a new one (and a new session) you may get what you want by using x11vnc (`apt-get install x11vnc`) for "attaching" to the already running X server (of whatever kind) using VNC. Run this on the machine running Eclypse ("remotehost") after logging in with ssh:

```
x11vnc -passwd somepassword -display :0
```

Then, on your current location:

```
vncviewer remotehost:0
```

If it doesn't work try :1, :2, etc. This assumes you can reach every port of `remotehost`. If you can't you may have to use ssh tunnels to forward port 5900 for display :0, 5901 for display :1 and so on:

```
ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 remotehost
```

And then:

```
vncviewer localhost:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having executed the process within `screen` or a similar utility, you're not going to be able to reattach the process using normal methods.

It looks like someone wrote some software to do this, however.  See: [Can I nohup/screen an already-started process?](https://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process)