# Is there a way to watch all screens output in a single place?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

having about 12 screens running long processes, I am willing to check out the state from time to time.

I would like to "tail -f " them all in a single console window so I don't have to switch between them every now and then.

Processes are running hence, IO redirection >> to a single file is currently not possible without stopping them - something I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of disown and multitail?

[Can I nohup/screen an already-started process?](https://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process)
http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/

Answer (score -2):

why to use many screens?

Use putty or reflection application and minimize the screens so you can look on one screen with many screens